# Accessing variables inside external class swift

Tags: ios, swift, class, variables

I have my `Viewcontroller.swift` file. This file contains 2 classes. One class is a global class called `Exercise` and the other class is just a normal Viewcontroller class. 
My `Exercise` class contains several variables, `excerciseReps` for example.
I am trying to access these variables in my Viewcontroller class to change their values. However, I am finding it difficult to access these variables so I can edit them, due to my limited understanding of swift. 
Can anyone shed some light on this for me? 
For example, changing the value of excerciseReps to "hello" when the done button is clicked ViewController class.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

private let reuseidentifier = "Cell"

struct cellData {
var opened = Bool()
var title = String()
var exerciseData = [String]()
var repsSetsWeightsData = [String]()
}


struct Contact {
var id:String = "Contact - \(UUID())"
var fullname: String
var exercises : [Exercise]
}

 class Exercise : NSObject , NSSecureCoding{

   static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool = true

   var excerciseName: String
   var excerciseReps: String
   var excerciseSets: String
   var excerciseWeights: String

    init(Name : String, Reps : String, Sets : String, Weights : String) {
    excerciseName = Name
    excerciseReps = Reps
    excerciseSets = Sets
    excerciseWeights = Weights
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(excerciseName, forKey: "excerciseName")
    aCoder.encode(excerciseReps, forKey: "excerciseReps")
    aCoder.encode(excerciseSets, forKey: "excerciseSets")
    aCoder.encode(excerciseWeights, forKey: "excerciseWeights")
    }

    required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let excerciseName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "excerciseName") as! String
    let excerciseReps = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "excerciseReps") as! String
    let excerciseSets = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "excerciseSets") as! String
    let excerciseWeights = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "excerciseWeights") as! String

    self.init(Name: excerciseName, Reps: excerciseReps, Sets: excerciseSets, Weights: excerciseWeights)

    }


}


class ContactController: UITableViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

//created items
//Done button for uipicker
let TheDoneButton: UIButton = {
    let Done = UIButton()
    Done.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)
    Done.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 10/255, green: 128/255, blue: 253/255, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
    Done.backgroundColor = .white
    Done.titleLabel?.font = Done.titleLabel?.font.withSize(20)
    Done.addTarget(self, action: #selector(uipickerDoneButtonPressed), for: .touchDown)
    Done.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return Done
}()


var tableViewData = [cellData]()
var contacts = [Contact]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //getting data from CoreData
    self.contacts = CoreDataManager.sharedInstance.retrieveDataFromCoreData()
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ExerciseCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ExerciseCell")

    for contact in contacts{
        //var sectionData = [String]()
        var exerciseData = [String]()
        var repsSetsWeightsData = [String]()
        for exercise in contact.exercises{
            let name = exercise.excerciseName
            let sets = exercise.excerciseSets
            let reps = exercise.excerciseReps
            let weights = exercise.excerciseWeights


            exerciseData.append(name)
            repsSetsWeightsData.append("Rep: " + reps + "   Set: " + sets + "   kg: " + weights)

        }

        self.tableViewData.append(cellData.init(opened: false, title: contact.fullname, exerciseData:exerciseData, repsSetsWeightsData: repsSetsWeightsData))
    }


    self.tableView.reloadData()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    self.navigationItem.title = "Workouts"

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: #selector(handleCancel))

    view.backgroundColor = .white
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseidentifier)

}


@IBAction func handleAddContact(_ sender: Any) {
    let controller = AddContactController()
    controller.delegate = self

    self.present(UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller), animated: true, completion: nil)

}


@IBAction func handleCancel(_ sender: Any){
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}


//UITABLEVIEW
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    //new
    return tableViewData.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                        numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     //new
    if tableViewData[section].opened == true {
        return tableViewData[section].exerciseData.count + 1
    }else {
        return 1
    }
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseidentifier, for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].title
        return cell
    }else {
        //use a different cell identifier if needed
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ExerciseCell", for: indexPath) as! ExerciseCell
        cell.exerciseLabel.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].exerciseData[indexPath.row - 1]
        cell.repsSetsLabel.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].repsSetsWeightsData[indexPath.row - 1]
        cell.repsSetsLabel.sizeToFit()
        // cell.textLabel?.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].sectionData[indexPath.row]
        //            cell.textLabel?.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].sectionData[indexPath.row - 1]
        return cell
        }
    }


    //did select row new
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened == true {
        tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened = false
        let sections = IndexSet.init(integer: indexPath.section)
        tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .none) //play around with animation
    }else {
        tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened = true
        let sections = IndexSet.init(integer: indexPath.section)
        tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .none) //play around with animation
    }
    }


    //this is the uipicker string variable this can be put up at the top of the page with all the other variables ...i think
var exercisesInSelectedWorkout = [String]()
var pickedExercise = String()

//being able to delete a row
// this method handles row deletion

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    // Edit Button
    let editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Edit", handler: { (action, indexPath) in

        print(self.contacts[indexPath.section].exercises)
        print(self.tableViewData[indexPath.section].repsSetsWeightsData)

        //setting exercisesInSelectedWorkout to exercise names within workout
        self.exercisesInSelectedWorkout = self.tableViewData[indexPath.section].exerciseData


        //creating uipicker
        var UIPicker: UIPickerView = UIPickerView()
        UIPicker.delegate = self as UIPickerViewDelegate
        UIPicker.dataSource = self as UIPickerViewDataSource

        //Calling UIPicker done buttons:
        self.view.addSubview(self.TheDoneButton)
        self.TheDoneButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.TheDoneButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
            self.TheDoneButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor ,constant: 40),
            ])

        //adding uipicker to screen
        self.view.addSubview(UIPicker)
        UIPicker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            UIPicker.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
            UIPicker.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor, constant: -150),
            //UIPicker.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.view.frame.width - 64)
            ])

        //locking tableview
        tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
    })
    editAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue


    // Delete Action UITableView
    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Delete", handler: { (action, indexPath) in

            //removing data from tableview
            self.tableViewData.remove(at: indexPath.section)
            tableView.deleteSections(IndexSet(integer: indexPath.section), with: .top)

            //Deleting Data from CoreData
            CoreDataManager.sharedInstance.deleteDataFromCoreData(contact: self.contacts[indexPath.section])
            print("Items removed from Table View")
            print("Row Deleted")
        })
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    return [editAction, deleteAction]
    }


    //UIPICKER Done button function (what happens when done is pressed)
@objc func uipickerDoneButtonPressed(){
    print(exercisesInSelectedWorkout)
    print("hi")
    print(pickedExercise)

}



    //UIPICKER
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return exercisesInSelectedWorkout.count
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    let row = exercisesInSelectedWorkout[row]
    return row
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent  component: Int) {
    let nameOfExercise = self.exercisesInSelectedWorkout[row] as String
    pickedExercise = nameOfExercise
    print(nameOfExercise)
}
}

    //this is an extention to addContactController. this is what happens when the done button is clicked in addcontactcontroller
extension ContactController: AddContactDelegate {
func addContact(contact: Contact) {

    self.dismiss(animated: true) {

        //Saving Data to CoreData
        CoreDataManager.sharedInstance.addContactsToCoreData(contact: contact)
        self.contacts.append(contact)

        //Settings values in table view
        var exerciseData = [String]()
        var repsSetsWeightsData = [String]()

        for exercise in contact.exercises{
            let name = exercise.excerciseName
            let sets = exercise.excerciseSets
            let reps = exercise.excerciseReps
            let weights = exercise.excerciseWeights

            exerciseData.append(name)
            repsSetsWeightsData.append("Rep: " + reps + "  Set: " + sets + "  Kg: " + weights)

        }
        //adding everything into tableview
        self.tableViewData.append(cellData.init(opened: false, title: contact.fullname, exerciseData:exerciseData, repsSetsWeightsData: repsSetsWeightsData))

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: `excerciseReps` is an instance variable. You would need an instance of the Exercise class. You would then say `myExerciseinstance.excerciseReps = "hello"`. Show your code in which you have such an instance, if that doesn't help.

Comment: Questions like this always come up, and it's really hard to answer them in short answers. The TL;DR is that classes don't really "exist", in a sense. Two classes can't really talk to each other. An object can be made of one class, and it can talk to an object of another class. That's what you need to do, to create an `Exercise` object, and give it to your `ViewController` object to use.

Comment: Please read [Classes And Structures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html) in the Language Guide

Comment: added all code, cannot seem to solve it. Just trying to set exerciseReps to "hello" when when the done button is pressed

Answer (score 0):

You can access the properties and methods outside their class in 2 different ways.

1: The most common way is to instantiate the class they are in and then access them through that like,

```
var ex = Exercise(Name : "name", Reps : "reps", Sets : "sets", Weights : "weight")

//then access them like this 
let name = ex.excerciseName
```

you may have to make the class and the variables public, and you will still need to create an object by instantiating like above.

```
    Public class Exercise {
       Pubic var excerciseName : String
    }
```

2: The second way is accessing static properties and methods without instantiating like

```
 let isSecure = Exercise.supportsSecureCoding
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a couple of things (I am not a pro, just trying to help)

1. make the class public (adding "Public" keyword before the declaration)
2. use a struct and mutate (use "mutating" before the function declaration) when changing a variable (this will "destroy" the struct and recreate it with the value modification done by the function)